# Alternative way to determine if a CultureInfo uses a specific language?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, cultureinfo

I need a way to detect if the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` uses a specific language.

In particular, I need to detect if the `CurrentCulture` `CultureInfo` object supports/uses/is "English", regardless of the country/region -- but, there is a possibility I would want to check for other languages, also.

I know that any English language `CultureInfo` objects' `Name`s will be prefixed with `en-` and then the region (`US`, `GB` etc.) - according to [MSDN's Table of Language Culture Name and Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx).

So I could simply check if the current culture name "starts with" the `en-` prefix:

```
var currentCultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
if (currentCultureName.StartsWith("en-"))
{
    // We have an English language culture
}
```

**EDIT**: Similarly (as [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk) pointed out) - if I were to use the `TwoLetterISOLanguageName`, I could end up with the same result:

```
var twoLetterISOLanguageName =
                          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

if (twoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals("en", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    // We have an English language culture
}
```

---

Is there an alternative, or more type-safe way of checking for this, with the possibililty of needing to detect other languages (e.g. French, German etc.)? - in order to save having to write a potentially large `switch` statement?

Or, is what I'm using above - and using a `switch` statement the best approach?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions :)

Comment: @CharithJ -- I must just point out it's not specifically to do with localized strings (I'm using language-specific .resx files, for that). I have a config file for app-specific settings for each customer's version of the app. In particular, there is a string that is in this config (let's call it `WelcomeText`) - so, some customers might want "Hello", or "Welcome" (all English) etc. But there is a specific customer that wants the app available in different languages, and I want to check if their language is "not English" in code, and then use the localized version, based on that language.

Comment: How many different languages you support?

Comment: At the moment, 2 - with a vision to support another on the way. It could be indefinite, though.

Comment: There is no really a very elegant solution, what you have suggested is not bad for a few languages.

Comment: OK, not to worry - I'm sure you'll agree it's a very unusual situation! - I just don't want to use a too "unorthodox" method of overcoming this issue. Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: I suppose you can just look at CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName (which will be "en" for "en-US", "en-GB" and so on).

Comment: Thanks, @Evk - This is something I've considered. I'm guessing I would still be in the same scenario as above (I'll update my answer to clarify your suggestion). Do you think what I have is sufficient?

Comment: Well then I don't understand your question I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

There is no really a very elegant solution, what you have suggested is not bad for a few languages. You could use [CultureInfo.Parent Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) which will return the neutral culture.

There are some complications when there is a hierarchy where multiple parent languages available (eg: some Traditional Chinese , Taiwan). But this should be fine for DE, FR and EN.

```
var neutralCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Parent.Name;

if (neutralCulture.Equals("en", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // We have an English language culture
}
else if (neutralCulture.Equals("fr", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // We have a French language culture
}
else if (neutralCulture.Equals("de", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // We have a German language culture
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you perhaps explain how I will be able to benefit from your suggestion compared to my suggestion - from what I can see uses the `CurrentCulture.Parent.Name`, and some extra `else if` statements?

Comment: You used CurrentCulture.Name and probably CurrentCulture.Parent.Name is slightly better..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you tell me what the difference is between the 2 and the advantages `CurrentCulture.Parent` has?

Comment: CurrentCulture.Name return the specific culture (eg: en-us) where as CurrentCulture.Parent.Name returns the parent/neutral culture (eg: en).

Comment: Ah, I see - makes more sense now (sorry, I must have been having a dumb Friday moment!). Good suggestion. Thank you :)

Comment: There are some complications when there is a hierarchy where multiple parent languages available (eg: some Traditional Chinese , Taiwan). But it should be fine for DE, FR and EN.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again! :)

Comment: And what about CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName?

Comment: @Evk: Yes that should be fine too for his required languages. Just another similar approach. Funny thing is that it returns 3 letters for some cultures ;-) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.twoletterisolanguagename(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use Equals and Ignore case instead of `==`? Is it not always ensured that it has the same casing or you did it just to be sure?